# Spark filter nested json on different data type

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am working in `Spark` and reading `Json` files. In `Json`, for a section I see different data types. For e.g. in the below `Json` structure, **abc** section is of type `struct` in first record but `string` type in second record. When I printed the schema via `df.printSchema`, it returned me `string` as data type for **abc** element. I want to filter the records based on the type so I want to retrieve only the records where **abc** is of `struct` type. Can someone guide me?

```
[
  {
    "abc":{
            "code":"TRS"
         }
  },
  {
    "abc": "{\"code\":\"TRS\"}
  }
]
```